# Checkout SVN with credentials in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: svn, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

How can I check out a Subversion repository that requires user credentials, via a Jenkins pipeline groovy script? It appears that the built-in `svn` command doesn't support credentials, so I tried code like this:

```
node {
    stage 'checkout'
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                      credentialsId: '34761a89-1402-47d7-96e2-aec22ffdc50b',
                      usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
        sh "svn co https://trac.nci.org.au/svn/cable/branches/$SVN_BRANCH --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD cable_branch"
    }
}
```

But this fails with

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: USERNAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:23)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:5)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the **Snippet Generator** for **General SCM** step. This displays the familiar Subversion configuration options, and takes credentials as parameter as usual.

The Snippet Generator will produce a tad ugly representation of your parameter selections and looks something like this:

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
          additionalCredentials: [], 
          excludedCommitMessages: '', 
          excludedRegions: '', 
          excludedRevprop: '', 
          excludedUsers: '', 
          filterChangelog: false, 
          ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
          includedRegions: '', 
          locations: [[credentialsId: '34761a89-1402-47d7-96e2-aec22ffdc50b', 
                       depthOption: 'infinity', 
                       ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
                       local: 'cable_branch', 
                       remote: "https://trac.nci.org.au/svn/cable/branches/$SVN_BRANCH"]], 
          workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
```

Notice that the **remote** section uses double quotes, so that the variable $SVN_BRANCH gets substituted correctly.

Comment: Hrm.. this looks like it will work, but the $SVN_BRANCH (which is a build parameter) doesn't expand, so I haven't managed to get it working yet. Once I figure that out//

Comment: Ok, this does work, when I use `remote: 'https://trac.nci.org.au/svn/cable/branches/' + SVN_BRANCH`. Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned in the end of the post, you need to use "double quotes" for the Groovy to expand the variable inside string.

Comment: What kind of credentials are credentialsId here? username and password?

Comment: @red888 It's the ID of the credentials entry you have configured in Jenkins, just add `/credentials` to your Jenkins-URL and you'll reach the credentials management.

Comment: Is it possible that the $SVN_BRANCH trick does not work in a multibranch pipeline?  I'm banging my head around this one...

Comment: Do we checkout git and svn in Jenking single job ?

Comment: If `SVN_BRANCH` is a job parameter, try using` ${params.SVN_BRANCH}` to refer to it (in which case I think you can just use single quotes; they don't prevent expansion of ${}.

Comment: I want to know from where and how do we get this parameter : credentialsId: '34761a89-1402-47d7-96e2-aec22ffdc50b'

Comment: how to handle svn shallow clone in this Jenkins file code while in checkout block ?

Comment: @AshishKarpe from the GUI "Manage Credentials" at a url similar to this one https://jenkins/manage/credentials/ (I had the same question). There is a list and it contains this ID/GUID

Answer (score 23):

Just adding some screen shots for OltzU's answer:

### Step 1:

[image]

### Step 2:

[image]