# Adding SCM credentials to jobs created through DSL in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, version-control, credentials, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to automate building of projects present in an SVN branch. i am using DSL to create new jobs for each project and then building them separately. I am able to create the new jobs for each project by looping over this:

```
job('JobName') {
    scm {    
        svn('MyURL')                    
    }
}
```

However, the url is internal and requires a username and password combination for Jenkins to be able to checkout from SVN. I know it can be easily done using the UI but for a large number of projects, this needs to be automated. How do we provide this credential in the DSL? Ideally, there would be a way to specify it along with the Url to SVN.
I have spent an entire day and more searching for an answer without much luck and would be really grateful for any help

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if this answer will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881132/checkout-svn-with-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline

Comment: That answer is about Jenkins Pipeline, but this question is about Jenkins Job DSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `svn` method has more options in a nested block which also allows to specify credentials:

```
job('example') {
  scm {
    svn {
      location('https://svn.mydomain.com/repo/project2/trunk') {
        credentials('company-svn')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case `company-svn` is the identifier of the credentials that are managed by the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin).

You can find all supported options in the Job DSL API Viewer:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-scm-svn-location-credentials

Comment: Works. Earlier, i looked at the xml generated by jenkins and to imitate it, I tried adding the credentials using the keyword 'credentialsId' instead of simply 'credentials'. Should have known better. Thanks.