# Checkout code from SVN in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Jenkins 2.1. My first step is to checkout code from SVN. For that I have referred [Checkout SVN with credentials in Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881132/checkout-svn-with-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline), but below are the queries I have.

1. I'm trying to understand on what basis the checkout syntax is written. I have understood `node` and `stage` but how `$class: 'SubversionSCM',locations:` and other parameters in checkout are defined ? Are we passing these as parameters to any plugin ? Please guide.
2. When I followed the code in my pipeline, I'm getting error. Below are the details.

**Pipleline Script**

```
node {

checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
          additionalCredentials: [], 
          excludedCommitMessages: '', 
          excludedRegions: '', 
          excludedRevprop: '', 
          excludedUsers: '', 
          filterChangelog: false, 
          ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
          includedRegions: '', 
          locations: [[credentialsId: '51cd938b-8c02-4526-8a99-85fad44025a2', 
                       depthOption: 'infinity', 
                       ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
                       remote: 'http://localhost:8083/!/#FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor']], 
          workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])


}
```

**Error**

```
  Running on master in C:\Users\HA\.jenkins\workspace\LoanProcessPipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
Checking out a fresh workspace because C:\Users\HA\.jenkins\workspace\LoanProcessPipeline\LoanProcessor doesn't exist
Cleaning local Directory LoanProcessor
Checking out http://localhost:8083/!/%23FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor at revision '2017-01-27T01:12:13.681 +0530'
ERROR: Failed to check out http://localhost:8083/!/#FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/!/%23FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://localhost:8083)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:134)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineProperties(DAVUtil.java:253)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineInfo(DAVUtil.java:201)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:196)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:480)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:833)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:119)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:170)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:134)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:996)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:972)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:948)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:897)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:833)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/!/%23FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://localhost:8083)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getResourceProperties(DAVUtil.java:79)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:101)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:123)
    ... 35 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to check out http://localhost:8083/!/#FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:130)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:170)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:134)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:996)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:972)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:948)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:897)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:833)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/!/%23FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://localhost:8083)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:134)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineProperties(DAVUtil.java:253)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineInfo(DAVUtil.java:201)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:196)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:480)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:833)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:119)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/!/%23FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://localhost:8083)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:70)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getResourceProperties(DAVUtil.java:79)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:101)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.findStartingProperties(DAVUtil.java:123)
    ... 35 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tested SVN URL and It Works fine in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://localhost:8083/!/#FirstRepo/view/head/LoanProcessor

That is a VisualSVN url.

http://localhost:8083/svn/FirstRepo/LoanProcessor

That would be your actual SVN URL. They are not the same, even though one resolves to the other in a browser.

You should definately learn how SVN works before you attempt to learn jenkins imo.

Comment: Thanks Cole9350 for pointing it out, it helped. Could you also help me to understand how the syntax is written (point 1). Any link will be helpful.

Comment: It is a groovy based syntax, classes are all defined in the javadoc http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/subversion/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.html . But really the point of the original post you were linking too was to say "Let the snippet generator do the work for you". And all you have to do is input the correct info. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator