# What to enter for "scm" in BlueOcean editor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I got stuck at first step using the easy BlueOcean editor. I am trying to create a first step Build / Check out from version control.

With one required field to enter *scm*. I tried the URL to my repo but the editor shows a message

> Expecting "class hudson.scm.SCM for parameter "scm" but got "whatever
>   I enter" of type class java.lang.String instead.

How can I enter a class and not a string in a string field?

What does BlueOcean expect from me at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have selected the `Git` option in the pipeline creation step. It will accept ssh connection to the repository that you would like to create a Blue ocean Pipeline. Select `Github/Bitbucket` if you have your code on one of those repositories.

Also, the blue ocean pipeline adds a `Jenkinsfile` to the repository so it needs SSH access.

So follow below steps.

1. Create a new SSH key on Blue Ocean instead of specifying a https URL
2. Add that key to Git repo settings
3. You should be able to create a new pipeline and authentication will happen.

I outlined this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTm9JgScUvU)

> Hope this helps. I dont have enough reputation to ask questions, hence answering straight away

Answer (score 0):

the BlueOcean Editor expects something like this (Example for SVN):

`[$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, credentialsId: 'Your Credential ID', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: 'SVN-REPO-Location']], quietOperation: true, workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']`

you can create this code with the code snippet editor as described here:([Checkout SVN with credentials in Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881132/checkout-svn-with-credentials-in-jenkins-pipeline)), just generate the snippet and cut out the class discription. Or paste the whole snippet into your pipeline as described here:([Jenkins Blue Ocean Provide Credentials for Subversion SCM Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597565/jenkins-blue-ocean-provide-credentials-for-subversion-scm-step/57608406#57608406))

Hope this helps!

Greetings,
bluescreenterror