# when I am using hudson tool CI to make new job this error appears, need solution

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, hudson, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Started by user anonymous
Building on master
Cleaning workspace C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.hudson\jobs\appnew\workspace
Checking out https://svn_srv/svn/ revision: Feb 8, 2017 1:20:37 PM depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
ERROR: Failed to check out https://svn_srv/svn/
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: No Credentials to try. Authentication failed.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
    at hudson.scm.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:90)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:682)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:371)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:359)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1032)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:175)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getRevisionNumber(SVNBasicDelegate.java:480)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.getLocations(SVNBasicDelegate.java:833)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNBasicDelegate.createRepository(SVNBasicDelegate.java:527)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:875)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:19)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:8)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1149)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$UpdateTaskImpl.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:129)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:152)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:830)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:813)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:794)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:793)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:775)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:786)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:729)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1558)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:518)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1495)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are trying to do ? Which command have you run and some details about your environment so people can help you

Comment: "No Credentials to try". Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068297/jenkins-subversion-error-e200015-no-credential-to-try-authentication-failed